# What to do with my website

Tags: jakarta-ee, web, hosting

I am learning xhtml and css for fun and have created a static website. I would like to maybe incorporate some j2ee components (I plan to learn them eventually) in the future, as well as have total control over the sites code. After reviewing some hosting options like go-daddy and IPage, it seems hosting services cater to things like wordpress, or provide some kind of drag n drop features to build a site. I want total control over everything except the hosting itself. I know this is a super noob question, but was curious what options I might have for something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most hosting sites DO cater to simplicity. But for the most part, hosting sites will utilize CPanel as the control panel you'll use to manage your website. And that is a VERY in depth control panel, you get control over every aspect of your site basically.

If you want ABSOLUTE control, I'd recommend getting a VPS or a Dedicated server, though the amount of control you get with CPanel is really insane. You won't commonly need a VPS or a dedicated server, trust me.

Websites tend to advertise they have drag and drop, wordpress, all that kinda stuff to get the laypeople to jump in, while the more experienced people will look through the specifics and see exactly what they're getting. It's an advertising ploy, not what they ARE serving in specific.

I personally use Hostgator for all of my hosting. They offer Website hosting, VPS and Dedicated servers. Their customer service is superb, and I have no complaints with their hosting.

You can use 64PennyHosting to get $9.94 off your next purchase at Hostgator, or 25Percent64 to get 25% off your next purchase.

If your purchase is over $40, 25% is more than $9.94, otherwise it's not. Hostgator's baby plan is $9.95 for the first month, so the $9.94 is designed to make that plan a penny.

Good luck finding with your website!

Comment: Just the info I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use Heroku and Git to set something up with full control and for free as described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/creating-apps).